# Django Form inital values don't work on render

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model `Transaction' and ModelForm to create one :

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    """ Invoice model.
     Represents a basic income/outcome transaction. """
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Title")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    operation = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=OPERATION_TYPE, verbose_name="operation")
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="value")
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CURRENCY_CHOICE, verbose_name="currency")
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Transactions"
        ordering = ["-date_created"]

class NewInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ("title", "category", "operation", "value", "currency")
        help_texts = {
            "operation": _("Money spent/received. For expenses use a negative value.")
        }
```

I have a Preference model linked with each user to store settings :

```
class Config(models.Model):
    """ Represents user's preferences. """
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name="config", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CURRENCY_CHOICE, default=DEFAULT_SETTINGS["currency"])
    language = models.CharField(max_length=56, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICE, default=DEFAULT_SETTINGS["language"])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "config"
        verbose_name_plural = "configs"
```

I'm trying to get user's currency from `Config` model as initial value for `Transaction` creation form. But initial value never renders.

My view :

```
def create_transaction_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewInvoiceForm(
            request.POST,
            instance=request.user
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            new_invoice = Transaction(**form.cleaned_data)
            # retrieving user's currency preference for further converting if income is different from base currency
            user_currency = request.user.config.currency
            # performing currency conversion to maintain consistent data for statistic and analyse
            if user_currency != new_invoice.currency:
                transaction_converted_value = CurrencyExchangeManager.currency_converter(
                    value=new_invoice.value,
                    exchange_to=user_currency,
                    base=new_invoice.currency
                )
                new_invoice.value = transaction_converted_value
                new_invoice.currency = user_currency
            new_invoice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', "/"))
```

I always get a 'dash' field as initial choice.
Appreciate any suggestions on this topics.

Comment: You can still set `initial` on a ModelForm. You don't have to only use `instance`. Where you state `I always get a 'dash' field as initial choice. Appreciate any suggestions on this topics.` do you mean a field with an empty value of `----`? That is because you aren't loading an initial value

Comment: Yeah, I was 'dash' means four dashes stands for empty value. 
I know about defining initial value in ModelForm itself but still I need to user request to get current user. I decided to render initials just on form render to get user from request and dynamically assign a user currency value taken from Config model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, but you need to check if it's handling both `GET` and `POST` requests appropriately for your form.

Here `request.method == "POST"` condition is crucial for processing form submissions, where you handle the data sent by the user. This block is where the form's data is validated and processed.

But when the user submits the form, this block takes charge, processing the submitted data, validating it, and then performing necessary operations like saving the data or doing additional processing, such as currency conversion in your case. **Till this point your code was correct.**

But for initial form rendering, particularly for `GET` requests, the form should be set up with initial values which is missing from your code.

When the form is first requested by the user, it's typically a `GET` request. In this scenario, you should provide initial values for the form fields. In your application, this means setting the initial value of the currency field to the user's preferred currency. You can do this by using the the `else` block of your view function, which handles the GET request like this:

```
else:
    user_currency = request.user.config.currency
    form = NewInvoiceForm(initial={'currency': user_currency})
```

The form is instantiated with the initial value for the currency, ensuring that when the user accesses the form to create a new transaction, they see their preferred currency pre-selected.

Here is the full update code that you need in `views.py` for `create_transaction_view` method

```
def create_transaction_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewInvoiceForm(
            request.POST,
            instance=request.user
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            new_invoice = Transaction(**form.cleaned_data)
            # retrieving user's currency preference for further converting if income is different from base currency
            user_currency = request.user.config.currency
            # performing currency conversion to maintain consistent data for statistic and analyse
            if user_currency != new_invoice.currency:
                transaction_converted_value = CurrencyExchangeManager.currency_converter(
                    value=new_invoice.value,
                    exchange_to=user_currency,
                    base=new_invoice.currency
                )
                new_invoice.value = transaction_converted_value
                new_invoice.currency = user_currency
            new_invoice.save()
     else:
          user_currency = request.user.config.currency
          form = NewInvoiceForm(initial={'currency': user_currency})

     return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', "/"))
```

Note: You can even optimize the code a little by initializing this `user_currency = request.user.config.currency` at the beginning of the `create_transaction_view` function so we don't need to repeat this twice in the code. I gave it like that for your understanding.

Comment: Unfortunatelly still not working. I was trying to do something similar by adding also form to GET request. Still getting empty value on form render.

Comment: did you try Initialising `user_currency = request.user.config.currency` before checking `if request.method == "POST":` ?

Comment: I did it in else as you have mentioned in your code sample. I also tried to specifie explicitly `if request.method == "GET"` instead of else. Both of this parts of code won't work.

Comment: Ok, that was my fault. I have a form used globally with context processor where that form initially renders. So the initals must have to passed in contex processor func. Thanks a lot for a help!

Comment: It's great to know it's fixed. Thank you